# List of denied item for a specific user

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sitecore, sitecore7.2

Is there the possibility to find for which items a specific user has access denied? Not from code, but directly from Sitecore.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Salut Marius,
using AccessViewer Application inside Sitecore you can select a user and view access rights.

Please see below picture

[image]

Comment: Well, yes. That I know. But I was wondering if there is a possibility to directly see only items that he has or doesn't have access on. Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such report out of the box. If code is not an option, you can try using the standard Access Viewer application: Login Desktop mode >Security Tools > Access Viewer

But you'll need to manually navigate through all tree nodes to see all item access rights.

See docs [here](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/70/security_administrators_cookbook_sc70-a4.pdf).